# How can I read a QR Code from a image in flutter using proper package?

Tags: flutter, dart, qr-code

I am building an app using flutter where I want to scan an image(that includes QR image). I am using packages available to read QR codes, but not working for me. Is there any package/solution to read a QR code from an image?

I Tried package:

> qr_code_tools: ^0.0.6

```
Future _getPhotoByGallery() async {
     var image = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
 String path = image.path;
 decode(path); 
}


Future decode(String path) async {
  print(path);
  String data = await QrCodeToolsPlugin.decodeFrom(path);
  setState(() {
    _data = data;
  });
}
```

I expect the output of QRCode from the selected image of Gallery.

But getting error here:

> QrCodeToolsPlugin.decodeFrom(path);//Null, Null something

Comment: On which device you are testing?

Comment: I am using my phone for testing

Comment: There's a permission you have to have for iOS.

Comment: sorry I am using android phone..

Comment: Did the app ask the permission to read the external storage?

Comment: no, but it access gallery anyway.

Comment: ANY SOLUTION please??

Comment: any solution ??

Comment: did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Even without providing the permission to your external storage, you can still access the gallery as the gallery is native to your device. However, your application will not be able to access the file that the gallery returns since it does not have the necessarry permission. To be sure, go to your app info and see whether the permission for the external storage was given. It is highly probable that you haven't given the permission to access the external storage. There are packages that allow you to check whether a permission was granted and one of them is *permission_handler*. So whenever you try to access your storage, check the permission first before accessing the gallery.
I might be wrong though.